# Javascript syntax error not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm rather new to JavaScript but I am learning..
But now I am stuck, I made this JavaScript Except I get Syntax error

```
$(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#date').datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
            }
        });
    });
});

if (!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)))) {

    $(function () {
        $("#startTime").timePicker({
            step: 15,
            endTime: "23:45"
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#endTime").timePicker({
            step: 15,
            endTime: "23:45"
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#breakTime").timePicker({
            step: 5,
            endTime: "03:00"
        });
    });
}
function SetDate(dt) {
    $('#date').val(dt);
}

var n = @(Model.Projects.Count);

function AddProject() {
    n++;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@(Url.Action("Project"))/" + n + "/?showDescription=false",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#projects').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

It is on my AddProject function I get my error, how ever I can't see what could be wrong?

And this is the view I want to use the script on.

```
                            @if (ViewData["posted"] != null)
                            {
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <strong>Inställningar sparade</strong>
                                </div>
                            }

                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                            {
                                <div class="portlet light">
                                    <div class="portlet-title">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">Inställngar</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Starttid:</td>
                                            <td>@Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime)</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Sluttid:</td>
                                            <td>@Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime)</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Rastlängd:</td>
                                            <td>@Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime)</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                                        <div id="projects">
                                            @foreach (var data in Model.Projects)
                                            {
                                                Html.RenderPartial("Project", data, ViewData["vd"] as ViewDataDictionary);
                                                var viewDataDictionary = ViewData["vd"] as ViewDataDictionary;
                                                if (viewDataDictionary != null)
                                                {
                                                    viewDataDictionary["id"] = (int)viewDataDictionary["id"] + 1;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                            <a href="javascript:AddProject()" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till projekt</a>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Spara</button>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you think `@(Model.Projects.Count);` is valid, any other external sources being used? Because that would not work for native JS. Also `"@(Url.Action("Project"))/"` probably needs to be `"@(Url.Action('Project'))/"`.

Comment: probably because it does not know who Model is. 
I'm learning javascript as well and i'm using Visual Studio code.

it also incorporates intellisence using typescript 

have a look at this : 
http://www.johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/

Comment: After a quick Google search it seems that @(Variable) is ASP.NET code. You need to keep in mind that Javascript runs on the browser, whereas ASP.NET runs on the server.

Comment: Try something like this to check your syntax http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Comment: ``@(Model.Projects.Count)`` looks like Razor syntax. Are you trying to mix data from your server and use it into your javascript? If so, where are your scripts located? In the same page?

Comment: url: "@(Url.Action("Project"))/" + n + "/?showDescription=false", Also seems to be incorrect

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek : Razor syntax *requires* the inner double-quotes. Your suggestion will cause an error in ASP.Net

Comment: There are two parts to this problem.1) Generating valid Javascript literals using Razor injection and 2) Solving any client-side JS bugs. I suggest you provide the *output* HTML of the page in your question too (e.g. as saved from your browser - Chrome F12 DOM inspector perhaps?), so we can see the actual DOM and script generated. Then the second part becomes easy.

Comment: P.S. I *strongly* advise against injecting Razor values into JavaScript as it is a maintenance problem and will not allow you to use VS to debug the scripts. Instead inject the values into the DOM in the view (e.g. `data-` attributes), or just a tiny snippet of global JS code at the top that your following code can access and put your JS into separate JS files..

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That's assuming the user is using ASP.Net, that's why I mentioned that the user probably needs to change it. It almost every other case and programming in general there should not be inner double-quotes. Which is why I asked the user what items that they are using, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek: `@Model.anything` is one of the most common ASP.Net Razor commands you will see. `@Url.Action()` is also 100% an ASP.Net Razor command. There is no doubt. This is 100% Razor code injection into JS. (Also the user's 3rd "top tag" is ASP.Net-mvc) - have added appropriate tags :)

Comment: Note: Ignoring the syntax bug for now, you also have loads of extra DOM ready handlers that can be reduced/removed.

Comment: Correct. This is a asp.net mvc5 projcet so I am using .net

Comment: Also added my view i want to use the script on, of course I could throw the script directly into the view but I would like to use that same script on two other pages. So I assume it would be best to have the script it it's own separate file. This is a asp.net mvc5 project @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript files do not support Razor compilation. Only views do that. You cannot have Razor in separate JS files.

Instead inject any required information into the view (e.g. into the elements as `data-` or other attributes) and have your JS pick up those values from the elements (or from a few global vars you set in the view).

I will add some examples for you...

### Example HTML (attribute injection):

```
<a id="addProject" href="@(Url.Action("Project") + "/{id}/?showDescription=false")" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg till projekt</a>
```

### JQuery

```
 $('#addProject').click(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      url = url.replace("{id}", myNewId);
      $.ajax({ 
         url: url
         ...
      });
 });
```

I strongly recommend never using inline event handlers (like `onclick=""`) with jQuery as the separate the event code from the registration aking maintenance harder and do not have all the same features as jQuery event handling.

### Example HTML (global var injection)

Place this code snippet in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript>
     var projectCount = @(Model.Projects.Count);
     // or
     window.projectCount = @(Model.Projects.Count);
</script>
```

Then you can access projectCount from other JS files with:

```
  var count = projectCount + 1;
```

or

```
  var count = window.projectCount + 1;
```